How to resolve "source value 8 is obsolete" warning in Android Studio?
I'm currently working on an Android project in Android Studio and I'm getting the following warnings:
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

I understand that these warnings are related to the Java version being used, but I'm not sure how to update the source and target values to fix this issue.
Could someone please guide me on how to update the Java source and target compatibility in my project, or if there’s another way to suppress these warnings?
Thank you

Read The Fine Manual.
In build.gradle put:
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

If using build.gradle.kts, put:
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

Doing either supplies defaults for sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility.
